# Shock Wave Initial Condtions

Tags: fluid-dynamics, shock-waves

So I am looking for a way to scale a translating shock wave in 1D, whose physics are governed by the Euler equations. Specifically, I would like $\rho_L=r\cdot\rho_R$ where $\rho$ is density, r is some multiplicative constant that I can specify, and $L$ and $R$ refer to the states immediately to the left/upstream and right/downstream of the shock. Also, the boundary moves at the same velocity as the neighboring fluid. However, I also need to enforce that both $P_L>1$ and $P_R>1$ where $P$ refers to pressure. Can anyone provide the initial conditions, which should be composed of 2 values for the left and right of the discontinuity for Pressure, Density and Velocity as well as a gamma for determining energy? So far, the only step forward I have found is that I can enforce the Rankine-Hugoniot condition for conservation of mass and momentum across the discontinuity (energy is not conserved as the volume moves). Thanks for any help or guidance.

Comment: The Rankine-Hugoniot relations only make sense in the shock rest frame.  Of course one can transform these quantities into any frame they wish, but it would only make things very complicated and difficult.  Also, you should specify in your question whether L refers to the upstream (i.e., pre-shocked) fluid or downstream fluid.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Edited. Thanks for the advice! Can you think of a reason that for the two test problems I have found for isolated shocks that the Rankine-Hugoniot relations hold for both mass and momentum? That is why I made the statement. Also, the speed of the wave is in agreement with both of these.

Comment: The Rankine-Hugoniot relations should always hold if the shock is a stationary, planar discontinuity that can be characterized as a shock, i.e., they are conservation relations for shocks/discontinuities.  In general, the RH relations will hold up to the order defined by your choice of the equation of state of the system.  It is also convenient that higher order terms tend to be less influential in most systems, thus one can often get away with only using up through energy or even stopping at the momentum flux density relations.